# Как отключить символы RLO, LRO и т.д.?

Tags: python, unicode

Есть бот для определенной платформы. В никах пользователей этой платформы иногда встречаются странные невидимые символы которые переворачивают текст задом на перед. В PyCharm эти символы показываются как `LRO, PDF, RLO, RLORLO, PDFRLO` и так далее. Как можно решить эту проблему ?

```py
# Тот самый символ
symbol_rlo = "‮"
```

Comment: что за платформа ?

Comment: показите ети символы в  "чистом " виде

Comment: покажите ваш способ решить проблему .